# Ordering items on the root api view for DefaultRouter

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm using the DefaultRouter provided by DRF because I need a root api view. However, the items on that view aren't in any logical order. I looked into the source and discovered that each entry is just put into a dictionary (which inherently isn't ordered).

```
class DefaultRouter(SimpleRouter):
    """
    The default router extends the SimpleRouter, but also adds in a default
    API root view, and adds format suffix patterns to the URLs.
    """
    include_root_view = True
    include_format_suffixes = True
    root_view_name = 'api-root'

    def get_api_root_view(self):
        """
        Return a view to use as the API root.
        """
        api_root_dict = {}
        list_name = self.routes[0].name
        for prefix, viewset, basename in self.registry:
            api_root_dict[prefix] = list_name.format(basename=basename)

        class APIRoot(views.APIView):
            _ignore_model_permissions = True

            def get(self, request, format=None):
                ret = {}
                for key, url_name in api_root_dict.items():
                    ret[key] = reverse(url_name, request=request, format=format)
                return Response(ret)

        return APIRoot.as_view()
```

I'd like to order the items on the root api view alphabetically and could easily do that by modifying the source. But I was wondering, have any of you come up with solutions to order the root api items without modifying the source code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Along the lines of what you suggest and of the first point in [Denis Cornehi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1194456/denis-cornehl)'s answer, here is an extension of DefaultRouter that orders the urls by their base_names:

```
# myapp/routers.py

from rest_framework import routers
from rest_framework import views
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.reverse import reverse
import operator
import collections


class OrderedDefaultRouter(routers.DefaultRouter):

    def get_api_root_view(self):
        """
        Return a view to use as the API root but do it with ordered links.
        """
        api_root_dict = {}
        list_name = self.routes[0].name
        for prefix, viewset, basename in self.registry:
            api_root_dict[prefix] = list_name.format(basename=basename)

        class APIRoot(views.APIView):
            _ignore_model_permissions = True

            def get(self, request, format=None):
                ret = {}
                for key, url_name in api_root_dict.items():
                    ret[key] = reverse(url_name, request=request, format=format)
                sorted_ret = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(ret.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(0)))
                return Response(sorted_ret)

        return APIRoot.as_view()
```

Answer (score 1):

With DRF 3.11.2 [not sure from which older version the below will work] you can also do

```
router = DefaultRouter()
# Register routes ...
router.registry.sort(key=lambda x: x[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two ways here:

- as you suggested, override the router, change the APIRoot view (returning an `OrderedDict` should be enough). In this case I addiotinally would raise an issue with DRF to (perhaps) change it for everyone.
- Extend/Override the JSONRenderer to allow sorting the keys when dumping the JSON. Then extend the BrowsableAPIRenderer to set this property. Or just sort all responses. (and, again, perhaps this is interesting for every user of DRF).